# When using the Kinesis Advantage keyboard, is it possible to press and hold the thumb keys without them terminating the keystroke?

Tags: keyboard, kinesis-advantage

I am using Mac OS X with a Kinesis Advantage keyboard and having some issues. I generally use Apple+Tab to switch applications, but when I do this with my Kinesis, it only opens the window switch dialog for a moment before closing; I think that the keyboard is terminating my keystroke early as some sort of accessibility option.

Can I turn this off somehow to allow "long holds" of the thumb keys? I've looked in the manual, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Kinesis Advantage, but I couldn't reproduce it. Have you tried resetting the settings by holding <kbd>Prgrm</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>?

Does it also apply to holding other keys? Or have you tried swapping command with some other key in System Preferences and holding that other key and tab?

If it's a hardware issue that only applies to some keys, you might use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to map some other key to command. For example I have moved all modifier keys under the left thumb:

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::DELETE, KeyCode::SHIFT_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::HOME, KeyCode::CONTROL_L</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::END, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
```